# subscript operator on pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I have a pointer to an object that has an overloaded subscript operator (`[]`) why can't I do this:

```
 MyClass *a = new MyClass();
 a[1];
```

but have to do this instead:

```
 MyClass *a = new MyClass();
 (*a)[1];
```

Comment: You could also do `a[0][1]` ;-)

Comment: I really wish we could just make a overload for a pointer...Can we?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because you can't overload operators for a pointer type; you can only overload an operator where at least one of the parameters (operands) is of class type or enumeration type.

Thus, if you have a pointer to an object of some class type that overloads the subscript operator, you have to dereference that pointer in order to call its overloaded subscript operator.

In your example, `a` has type `MyClass*`; this is a pointer type, so the built-in `operator[]` for pointers is used.  When you dereference the pointer and obtain a `MyClass`, you have a class-type object, so the overloaded `operator[]` is used.

Comment: Just like `->` and `.` are differentiated.

Answer (score 8):

Because `a` is type pointer to a MyClass and not a MyClass. Changing the language to support your desired use would make many other language semantics break.

You can get the syntactic result you want from:

```
struct foo {
    int a[10];
    int& operator [](int i) { return a[i]; }
};

main() {
    foo *a = new foo();
    foo &b = *a;
    b[2] = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Good news. You can also do...

a->operator[](1);

To add on to the preferred answer, think of operator overloading as overloading functions.

When overloading member function of a class, you remember that the pointer is not of that class type.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, with `a[1]` the `a` pointer is treated as memory containing array, and you're trying to access the 2nd element in the array (which doesn't exist).

The `(*a)[1]` forces to first get the actual object at the pointer location, `(*a)`, and then call the `[]` operator on it.