# Array subscript operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having trouble understanding the difference between `Array obj;` and `Array* obj = new Array;` while overloading the array index operator `[]`. When I have a pointer to the object, I get these error messages on **VS 2010**.

**error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

    could be 'Array &Array::operator =(const Array &)' while trying to match the argument list '(Array, int)'**

```
#include <iostream>
class Array
{
    int arr[10] ;

    public:
       int& operator[]( int index )
       {
           return arr[index] ;
       }
};

int main()
{
    //Array* obj = new Array; Error

    Array obj;   // Correct
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
        obj[i] = i;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one explain the rationale between the two kind of instances for operator overloading? Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808030/subscript-operator-on-pointers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case of `Array *obj`, `obj[i]` is the equivalent of `*(obj+i)`, so it evaluates into an `Array` object.

You would have to do

```
int main()
{
    Array* obj = new Array;

    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
        (*obj)[i] = i;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "so it evaluates into an Array object" is a very strange and vague claim.  I'd say it assumes obj is first in a contiguous array of Arrays, and moves to the (i+1)th (array indexing being 0 based).  What then happens is that it tries to assign i directly into that the Array object at that address, and there's no `Array::operator=(int)` nor `Array(int)` constructor so that's not possible.  Just as well ;-), as a silent error like that would create undefined run-time behaviour and be harder to notice and fix.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `operator[]` for `Array`, not for `Array*`. In the commented-out code, you create an `Array*`. In fact, you cannot overload an operator for any pointer type. Applying `[]` to a pointer treats it as an array, converting the array indexing into pointer arithmetic. Thus, applying `[]` to an `Array*` yields an `Array` (really an `Array&`). You can't assign an `int` to an `Array` because you didn't define that (and don't want to, either).

Modern, well-written C++ uses the keyword `new` very seldom. You should not be suspicious that your C++ code doesn't contain the keyword `new`. You should be suspicious every time it **does**!