# Subscripting/Indexing a Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, indexing

I'm working through some code for a class I'm taking, and since I'm not familiar with C++ I am confused by subscripting pointers.

## My assumptions:

`&` prefixed to a variable name, gives you a pointer to the memory address of that value and is roughly inverse to `*` prefixed to a variable name, which in turn gives you the value that resides at a particular memory address.

Pointers are subscriptable, so that `ptr[0] == ptr` and `ptr[n] == ptr + (n * data_bytes)`, where `data_bytes` depends on the particular type of the pointer (eg. 4 bytes wide for 32-bit ints).

## The Problem:

When I want to subscript the memory address, I have to put it in a variable first, and I don't understand why I can't just subscript the variable directly.

## Minimal Code Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int val = 1;
    int *val_ptr = &val;

    cout << &val << endl;

    // works
    cout << val_ptr[0] << endl;

    // does not work
    // cout << &val[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## Addendum

I am aware of some related questions, but they didn't really help me understand this specific issue.

I looked at:

- [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)
- [how does the ampersand(&) sign work in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857857/how-does-the-ampersand-sign-work-in-c)
- [subscript operator on pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808030/subscript-operator-on-pointers)
- [Subscripting integer variable using a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345691/subscripting-integer-variable-using-a-pointer)

and while this is almost certainly a duplicate (I will hardly be the first person that's confused by pointers), or maybe even has an answer that I overlooked in the linked questions, I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Operator precedence. `[]` is considered before `&`. Do `(&val)[0]` instead.

Comment: You forgot to ask the question. "I don't understand" and "it does not work" are not questions. Do you want to understand it or make it working?

Comment: When I want to subscript the memory address, I have to put it in a variable first, and I don't understand why I can't just subscript the variable directly.

Comment: It's in there, but I agree, that it doesn't stand out enough. Would you think putting this at the start would improve readability/understandability?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thank you! That makes total sense. If you want to publish this as an answer I will accept immediately

Comment: @273K just adding the ping. Also saying "I don't understand why ..." clearly implies a question, but if you want to be pedantic about it, I can change the wording =)

Comment: `ptr[0] == ptr and ptr[n] == ptr + (n * data_bytes)` are both incorrect.  We don't say that an address and the value at that address are `==` equal.  For a pointer `p` and integer `i`, by definition `p[i] == *(p + i) == *(i + p) == i[p]`.  Note that `int(p + i) == int(p) + i * sizeof(*p)`, that is, the multiplication by element size applies during pointer arithmetic.  So `ptr + (n * bytes_per_element)` is wrong, it would multiply by element size twice.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the clarification and pointing out, that I missed the asterisks!
So you are saying that adding the 'offset' manually doesn't make sense, because C++ does it automatically?
Therefore, I should change my assumption to `ptr[n] == *ptr + n` for it to be correct, right? 
(adding the asterisk and getting rid of the manual offsetting)
Also thanks for suggesting the more idiomatic `sizeof`

Comment: `ptr[n] == *(ptr + n)`, that's actually the definition of the `[]` operator (array subscripting).  The parentheses are needed, due to operator precedence (which is what your question turned out to be about), if you write just `*ptr + n` that would be the same as `ptr[0] + n` not `ptr[0 + n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ted Klein Bergmann's comment, there was a problem with operator precedence.

> `[]` is considered before `&`. Do `(&val)[0]` instead.

So a working example would be

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int val = 1;

    // does work now
    cout << (&val)[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```